# Looking to emboss a white logo around my tennis ball (which doesn't have the hair particle property added to it)

Tags: uv, hair, shrinkwrap

[image]Hi fellow blender users!

I'm still very new to blender, and for the death of me cant figure out how is best to resolve this issue I'm running into, maybe someone can run me through how to do this/ have any tips? :)

I've added a hair particle property to the majority of the tennis ball, apart from certain engraved areas which are white. What Im trying to do is add a white logo (the turtle illustration) to my tennis ball and I want this logo to look similar to the white sections of the tennis ball, so that this logo doesn't have hair coming out from it.

At the moment I have added a shrink wrap modifier to the logo layer, and this is basically just projecting the logo on top of the tennis ball, which means the hair particle properties are still coming up and out through the logo. I want this logo area to be without hair :))

Hopefully this makes sense :)

Link to the blender file is here if its needed to further look into: https://we.tl/t-hOARXgI3yf :)))

Comment: Instead of using a Shrinkwrap you could use it on the image texture of your ball

Answer (score 3):

in your particle settings, field weights -> density/length use a vertex group.

you can influence this vertex group with a vertex weight mix modifier

[image]

the "magic" will be done by the influence -> mask texture which should be a black/white texture so that it can define where the hair should be and where it shouldn't

[image]

---

update:

to your provided file:

1. the vertex weight mix modifier has to be before the particle modifier. Blender works the modifiers down, so if Blender renders the particles, the weight of the vertices aren't changed at all
2. you didn't fill in any vertex group for "B" -> choose Group

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks so much for the speedy reply! this technique rings a bell as this is what I used to determine that the hair wont be applied to the white embossed areas of the tennis ball, however I still cant apply this to the illustration, I think maybe i'm doing something wrong with the mask texture section? 

I have updated the post with a wetransfer link to the file, if you have 5 seconds could you scan over it and see if you can spot where I'm going wrong? absolutely no worries if not!! dont expect you to spend your own time on this :)) and again thanks so much in advance! :))

Comment: i updated my answer